# Formula field for Contact's organisation

Tags: formula-field

I have a requirement to Create a formula field “Organisation Phone” in contact object which should be displaying [Phone] field from Contact’s Organisation.

The formula I have is below:
IF(
NOT(ISBLANK( Organisation_Name__c)),
$Organization.Phone,
""
)

but it does not fetch the required results as there is no value in this field even though the phone field has the value in organisation.

I'm not sure what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Check if Organisation_Name__c is really populated or not.

Comment: it is populated just double checked.

Comment: Where are you populating the Phone? Have you checked that is there?

Answer (score 1):

`$Organisation` is a [global variable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_organization.htm) that refers to your Salesforce instance organization (Setup > Company Information), not the contact's account.  If you want to refer to the contact's account, you need to use the lookup field name with "__r".  Example: if your lookup field is Organisation_Name__c, then you can reference the phone field as Organisation_Name__r.Phone

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple.

Account.phone

If contact's organisation has the phone number above formula would ensure that is filled in Organisation Phone field.